# How to set up dynamic filter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have client that want me to set up dynamic parameter in SSRS. currently i'm using SSRS 2008. i have tried googling and anything, but i find nothing. is there anyone know. how to set up dynamic filter in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add a new parameter with multivalue instead.

If you want to have the parameter field added dynamically at run time, I am afraid you are not able to. You need to define your parameter first before run the report and the defined parameter will be used at run time.

Cheers,